# Uploading Image in Reactjs form

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck with uploading files in ReactJS.just got two confusion one is how to add room image on data and another one  implementing FormData in below code what i tried  is given below?

**code**

```
    const initial_data={
     Roomtype:"",
     Roomprice:"",
     Roomimage:""
    }
    const[data,setData]=useState(initial_data)
    
    const handleiInputChange=e=>{
    setData{...data,[e.target.name]:e.target.value}
    
    //axios post code for Create
    
    
    
    return(
    <div>
    <input type="text" onchange={handleInputChange} name=Roomtype......./>
 <input type="text" onchange={handleInputChange} name=Roomprice......./>
    <input type="file" onchange={handleInputChange} name=Roomimage......./>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't on the right track, from what I am seeing I think you only uploading a single picture, so instead of creating a function you can just set the state inside the `input` field.

```js
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.files[0])} ...../>
```

and inside your submit function

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Roomimage", data.Roomimage);
formData.append("Roomtype", data.Roomtype);
formData.append("Roomprice", data.Roomprice);

axios.post('your url',formData)
//..
```

Comment: FormData does not hold value of roomtype and roomprice if we want to call post axios

Comment: @surajdhungana you can append those too, I edited the answer check it out.